# Form validation and passing model back to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have setup validation in my viewmodel such as the below:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
[StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password must be the same")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

When I submit the form I check if `ModelState.IsValid` and if its not valid then return the original view but by doing this I lose the original data I had in my model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Form(MemberAddViewModel viewModel, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

       ...
    }

    return View("Form", viewModel);
}
```

I would have expected the `viewModel` to be passed back to the original `View` but it seems only model items populated in the view are. What is best practice for this? Hidden fields / Session data?

Comment: ...unless you're talking of data fetched from a database, or another source, here, in which case, you do have to rebuild that part of your model.  A common scenario for that is having to rebuild dropdownlists.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. You can always pass a model (or viewModel, etc) to a view. What model type is your view expecting?

Comment: I have some profile fields which are from the DB and feed a list of countries the user is from and their gender. I assign these to a property of my viewmodel and then dynamically create the drop down lists in the view. But these are lost when I then submit the form in the first step for client validation. I need to regenerate these again? If so I might right my own JS for client side validation

Comment: You don't need to necessarily create extra validation for this.  Taking the example in my answer below, you can decorate `EmployeeId` with the `[Required]` attribute, which will ensure the user has selected an option from the list.  This works for client-side validation, too.  Unless of course, you're talking about the rebuilding of the lists themselves.  In which case, you could easily setup helper methods to do so on your controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why you have to rebuild parts of the model, you need to think about what's going on under the hood when the model binder is passed the data from your view.  A `SelectList` is a perfect example of this.

Let's say you have a view model as follows:

```
public class EmployeesViewModel
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public SelectList Employees { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

Here, `EmployeeId` represents the `Id` of the selected `Employee` from the `SelectList`.  So let's assume you have a controller action like this, which populates the `SelectList` and passes the data to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new EmployeesViewModel();
    model.Employees = new SelectList(/* populate the list */);
    return View(model);
}
```

Now let's assume a user comes along, navigates to this view, chooses an employee from the list, and POSTs the data back to the server.  When this happens, the only thing that gets submitted from that form, *is the* `Id` *of the* `employee`.  There's no need for HTTP to transport all of the other options from the `SelectList` to the server, because a) they haven't been selected and b) you have that data on the server already.

Comment: yes got it, my understanding was that System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute was client side validation though? Server side should only be needed if they have JS disabled

Comment: @PhilipABarnes You can never trust data sent from the client.  Validation must always occur on the server.  JS is essentially there to improve the responsiveness of your application (e.g. avoiding unnecessary round trips).

Comment: i have a PHP background and my issue isnt architecture but more understanding how MVC works. `System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute` I was expecting to be client side?

Comment: @PhilipABarnes It works for both client-side and server-side.  `ModelState.IsValid` is telling you precisely whether the validation rules you've applied to your model have passed or not.  It's the reason why these attributes are so powerful.

Comment: got it, I think I need to add some JS files to my View for the client side to work.

Comment: @PhilipABarnes When you created the view, did you ensure that `Reference script libraries` was checked?  It adds `script` tags to insert `jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` automatically (as long as you tell it to create something other than an empty view).

Comment: I create empty views and do not check the strongly type box so have not so far, will look more into this tomorrow - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure for I undertandood your question... This is how i populate lost fields: i divide model population into 2 parts: for editable props (elements that being posted back to server) and non-editable (that are getting lost on postback)

```
// View model
public class MyModel
{
    public MyModel() { }

    public MyModel(Entity e, ContractTypes[] ct)
    {
        // populate model properties from entity
        ContractTypeId = e.ContractTypeId;
        // and call magic method that'll do the rest my model needs
        PopulateNonEditableFields(ct);
    }

    public void PopulateNonEditableFields(
        Dictionary<int, string> ContractTypes [] ct)
    {
        // populate dictionaries for DDLs
        ContractTypesList = new SelectList(..., ct,...);
    }

    // model properties
    public ContractTypeId { get; set; }
    public SelectList ContractTypesList { get; set; }
}

// controller action
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(MemberAddViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

       ...
    }
    // user input stays as-is but need to populate dictionaries and evrithing
    // that was lost on postback
    viewModel.PopulateNonEditableFields(context.ContractTypes.GetAll());
    return View("Form", viewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you have data in the view model which is not posted back through the form. There can be many valid reasons why this is the case.

Another alternative is to always create the view model manually, and then update it using the posted back values through a call to `TryUpdateModel`. Calling `TryUpdateModel` will do two things: set the model's public properties using the controller's value provider, then runs validation checks on the model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(int id, string returnUrl)
{
     MemberAddViewModel viewModel = CreateViewModel(id);  // Populates with 
                                                          // intial values
     if(TryUpdateModel(viewModel))
     {
         // If we got here, it passed validation
         // So we continue with the commit action
         // ...
     }
     else // It failed validation
     {
         return View("Form", viewModel);
     }
}
```